# Error importing Switch when using create-react app

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-deployment-project

[image: Image of the Error shown]

I really do not know how to resolve this issue. I need help...

the Error states; "export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possib:

I can't create a link tag in react due to this error. I do need help with this...

the error is cleared anytime I remove the switch tag but the link doesn't still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react-router-dom v6, `Switch` is replaced by `Routes`.
You need to update the import from

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

[react-router-v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5)

Comment: Thank you @Rohith 
the error is gone but my page displays blank now. The only thing that works is if I remove the {Routes, Route} I imported

Comment: Do you have a repo in Github with the code?

Comment: Yes I do...

I've resolved the code but the link doesn't work

Comment: https://github.com/Vicwin13/linkTree/blob/main/linktr/src/App.js